# Configure multiline from filebeat tomcat module

Tags: tomcat, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I'm using filebeat 7.15 with tomcat module to send logs to kibana. I'm trying to send exceptions as one message.

My tomcat.yml configuration looks like this.

```
- module: tomcat
  log:
    enabled: true
    var.input: file
    var.paths: ["catalina.out"]
    input:
      multiline.pattern: "^[[:space:]]*at |^Caused by:"
      multiline.negate: false
      multiline.match: after
```

Now whenever an exception happens,  in kibana log stream all lines of an exception are missing (so they are glued together I assume), but the event is missing message and prints "failed to find message". There is also "log.flags: multiline", but I can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

Edit:
Couldn't get this to work, eventually disabled the tomcat module and configured log input with multiline and pipeline in filebeat.yml.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the documentation for multiline pattern here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html

According to this usual Java exception multiline should have this pattern:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: A book has a null property
       at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookIds(Author.java:38)
       at com.example.myproject.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.example.myproject.Book.getId(Book.java:22)
       at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookIds(Author.java:35)
       ... 1 more
```

```yaml
multiline.type: pattern
multiline.pattern: '^[[:space:]]+(at|\.{3})[[:space:]]+\b|^Caused by:'
multiline.negate: false
multiline.match: after
```

In this example, the pattern matches the following lines:

- a line that begins with spaces followed by the word at or ...
- a line that begins with the words Caused by: